# How to preserve file format when using loudnorm? (bitrate / sample rate etc)

Tags: ffmpeg

I run `loudnorm` to normalize my audio file:

```
ffmpeg -i debugAudio.m4a -filter:a loudnorm=I=-30 output6.m4a
```

I noticed that the output has different sample rate and bitrate than the original file. Is there any way to make sure that ffmpeg uses the sample format for the output as the original file?

If this can't be done with one flag, what arguments should I specify to make sure that no changes are made to the file apart of its volume?
I know I can manually set sample rate with `-ar`. What should I use for bitrate? Is there any other attribute I should set?

Comment: You'll need to probe the sample rate beforehand and then set that using `-ar`. Similar is true for bitrate.

Comment: @Gyan how to I know what bitrate to set? How can I properly read it from the original file?